# How to make a switch statement accept a percentage instead of a letter grade?

Tags: c

I'm trying to figure out how to get the user to input a percentage and have it spit out a letter grade. When I run the program, it doesn't even step into the cases.

Expected input: Please enter your grade: 70
Expected output: You got a C!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int percent;
    printf("Please enter your grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &percent);

    switch (percent)
    {

        case 1:
            (percent >= 90);
            puts("You got an A!");
            break;

        case 2:
            (percent >= 80);
            puts("You got a B!");
            break;

        case 3:
            (percent >= 70);
            puts("You got a C!");
            break;

        case 4:
            (percent >= 60);
            puts("You got a D!");
            break;

        case 5:
            (percent < 60);
            puts("You got an F!");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: regarding these kinds of statement: ` (percent >= 90);`  these will not compile!  A `switch()` statement only handles one value per `case` and this code is trying to handle a range of values per case.  Strongly suggest using a series of `if/else if` statements instead

Comment: the posted `case` values are 1 percent, 2 percent, etc.  not what you want

Comment: @user3629249 - a statement `(percent >= 90)` will compile.   It won't do what the OP expects though   (it has no observable effect, since it computes a result and discards it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this may work. Cases 10 and 9 fall through and cases 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0 fall through.

As @rici pointed out, `%` does not work here but `/` does.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void){
    char input[100] = "";
    int percent = 0;
    int result = 0;

    do {
        printf("Please enter your grade 0 to 100: " );
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            result = sscanf ( input, "%d", &percent);
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( result != 1 || percent < 0 || percent > 100);

    switch( percent / 10){

        case 10:
        case 9:
            puts ("You got an A!");
            break;

        case 8:
            puts ("You got a B!");
            break;

        case 7:
            puts ("You got a C!");
            break;

        case 6:
            puts ("You got a D!");
            break;

        case 5:
        case 4:
        case 3:
        case 2:
        case 1:
        case 0:
            puts ("You got an F!");
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the place for a switch statement; it's the perfect place for an if/else ladder.

```
if (percent >= 90) {
    puts("You got an A!");
} else if (percent >= 80) {
    puts("You got a B!");
} else if (percent >= 70) {
    puts("You got a C!");
} else if (percent >= 60) {
    puts("You got a D!");
} else {
    puts("You got an F!");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I had it at first. I wanted to do it as a switch statement for practice.